# Update Sub-collections on CloudFunctions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I need help with something.

I have 2 collections on my project, one is called Products and another called Users.

I’m duplicating the selected product information into a sub-collection of users as favorites, in this case:

users(collection) > user(doc) > favorites(collection) > product (doc)

My idea is to create a cloud-function that will watch for any updates on any product in the "product collection" product(collection) > product(doc) and then reflect those changes on the users > favorites sub-collection by updating the values of the products here:

users(collection) > user(doc) > favorites(collection) > product (doc)

How is this possible from index.js ? This my code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

    exports.updateFavoritedProducts = functions.firestore.document('products/{productId}').onUpdate((change, context) => {

admin.firestore().collection('products').get(queryProductsSnapshot => {

    queryProductsSnapshot.forEach(productQuery => {
    const pricePQ = productQuery.price;

    console.log('tetesfsf');

    return admin.firestore().collection('users').get(queryUsersSnapshot => {
            queryUsersSnapshot.forEach(userSnapshot => {

                return admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(userSnapshot.id).collection('favorites').get(queryUserProductsSnapshot => {
                    queryUserProductsSnapshot.forEach(queryUserProductSnapshot => {
                        if (queryUserProductSnapshot.id === productQuery.id) {

                            return admin.firestore().doc(`users/${userSnapshot.id}/favorites/${queryUserProductSnapshot.id}`).update({ amountVolume: '123456'
                            })
                        } else {
                            console.log("No events found");
                            return null
                        }
                    })
                });
            })
            })
    });
})
});
```

Comment: There are two `QuerySnapshot.forEach` loops in your code, and it seems that one of them is not finding any documents. It seems that you should check if the `QuerySnapshot` is null before calling any methods on it.

Comment: This is still not working on my end;  Do you know how to rewrite this code so that it can make the update within the "favorites subcollection" once the update is made at the "products collection" level?

Comment: Did you add the `if` checks that I mentioned? If so, and the error still occurs, update your question to show the updated code.

Comment: I figured it out and posted the solution here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out how to do this with nesting promises. Here is the solution:

```
exports.updateFavoritedProducts = functions.firestore.document('products/{productId}').onUpdate((change, context) => {
    const data = change.after.data();
    const productID = data.id;

 return db.collection('products').where('id', '==', productID).get().then((productsQuerySnap) => {

    productsQuerySnap.forEach((productQuerySnap) => {
        const newPrice = productQuerySnap.data().price;
        const newPriceUnit = productQuerySnap.data().priceUnit;

        db.collection('users').get().then((usersQuerySnap) => {
            usersQuerySnap.forEach((userQuerySnap) => {

                return db.collection('users').doc(userQuerySnap.id).collection('favorites').doc(productQuerySnap.id).update({ 
                    price: newPrice,
                    priceUnit : newPriceUnit

                 }).catch((err) => {
                    console.log('Error getting documents', err);
                    return Promise.reject(err);
                    });
                });
                return null
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log('Error getting documents', err);
                return Promise.reject(err);
            });
        return null
    });
    return null
})
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log('Error getting documents', err);
        return Promise.reject(err);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to create a Cloud Function that triggers on all product updates for all users, you declare it as:

```
functions.firestore.document('users/{userId}/products/{productId}').onUpdate((change, context) => {
```

If you then want to access `userId` or `productId` inside the function body, you can get them as:

```
context.params.userId
context.params.productId
```

Comment: But the change is not happening in that path! The initial change is happening at products > productId. Once this happens; I want to update the info in the following path: users/{userId}/products/{productId} . so I need to call my function to trigger on the product collection change and not the User

Comment: Your code already triggers on the right path in that case. What's the problem with it?

Comment: Once it is triggered; How can I update the changes in the other collection: users(collection) > user(doc) > favorites(collection) > product (doc) . I just edited my question with what I tried and still not working;

Comment: What isn't working about this code? Keep in mind that Stack Overflow is a notoriously inefficient interactive debugger, so it's best if you can tell us as much as possible about: what line isn't doing what you expect it to do, and what all the relevant values are before that line (typically by logging their value, and including that code and its output in your question).

Comment: I just updated the post with the error code I get in logs. Do you know how I can change the code so I can make this update possible for the favorites subcollection within users collection?  Not sure where exactly in my code I am doing wrong that does not update the subcollection once I update a field in product collection

Answer (score 0):

I used user1889692's answer to update all the documents in a even deeply nested sub-collection in my project.

timeline(collection) > timeline(doc) > publisherId(collection) > publisherIdId(doc) > posts(collection) > postId(doc)

[image]

This is my working code:

```
 exports.onCreateTimelineTest = functions.firestore
   .document("/timelineTest/{buguId}")
   .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {

 const timeNow =new Date();
 const db = admin.firestore();
     return db.collection("timeline")
     .get()
     .then((timelineQuerySnapshot) => {
     timelineQuerySnapshot.forEach(async(timelineQuerySnapshot) => {


       console.log("all the documnets inside timeline are", timelineQuerySnapshot.id);

        await db.collection("timeline")
        .doc(timelineQuerySnapshot.id)
         .collection("publisherId")
         .get()
         .then((publisherSnapshot)=>{
         publisherSnapshot.forEach(async(publisherSnapshot)=>{


           console.log("all the documnets inside timeline are", publisherSnapshot.id);

         await db.collection("timeline")
          .doc(timelineQuerySnapshot.id)
          .collection("publisherId")
          .doc(publisherSnapshot.id)
          .collection("posts")
          .where('uploadTime', '<=', timeNow)
          .get()
          .then((postSnap)=>{
         postSnap.forEach(async(postSnap)=>{


         console.log("all the documnets inside timeline are", postSnap.id);

         return db.collection("timeline")
         .doc(timelineQuerySnapshot.id)
         .collection("publisherId")
         .doc(publisherSnapshot.id)
         .collection("posts")
         .doc(postSnap.id)
         .set({
         'name': 'madhav'
                          }).catch((err)=>{
                          console.log('Error getting documents', err);
                          return Promise.reject(err);
                          });
                       });
         return null
         }).catch((err) => {
                    console.log('Error getting documents', err);
                    return Promise.reject(err);
                   });
         });
         return null
         }).catch((err) => {
          console.log('Error getting documents', err);
          return Promise.reject(err);
         });
     });
     return null
     }).catch((err) => {
      console.log('Error getting documents', err);
      return Promise.reject(err);
     });

  });
```