# How to fix Value for argument "documentPath" is not a valid resource path?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to trigger a function which the token will be accessed on a subcollection, going through documents without specifying it. In dart I could use documentId for it, can I have something similar with javascript? Tried the following but it returns me:

> Value for argument "documentPath" is not a valid resource path

Any lights on how to fix it? thanks in advance for your help!

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

 var msgData;
 var documentId = admin.firestore.FieldPath.documentId();



exports.chatTrigger = functions.firestore.document(
 'chat/{chatId}/users/{usersId}/messages/{messagesId}')
 .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
  msgData = snapshot.data();

return 
 admin.firestore().collection('chat').doc(documentId)
 .collection(documentId).doc(documentId)
 .collection('messages').get().then((snapshots) => {
   var tokens = [];
   if (snapshots.empty) {
        console.log('No Devices');
        return false;


     } else {
      for (var token of snapshots.docs) {
          tokens.push(token.data().token);
      }

      var payload = {
         "notification": {
             "title": msgData.name,
             "body": msgData.title,
             "sound": "default"
          },
          "data": {
             "sendername": msgData.name,
             "message": msgData.title,
         }
       }

       return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload).then((response) => {
          console.log('Pushed them all');
       }).catch((err) => {
           console.log(err);
       })
     }

   })
})
```

I believe my documentId on 'admin.firestore().collection('chat')
.doc(documentId).collection(documentId).doc(documentId).collection('messages').' is not returning me what I expected it to do.

Comment: Please edit the question to be more specific about what you're doing that causes the error, what line it's on, and what you've done so far to debug it.  What you have right now is just not enough information to work with.  Ideally, your question contains enough information so that anyone can reproduce the issue on their own.

Answer (score 2):

Found my answer on [Update Sub-collections on CloudFunctions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58653220/update-sub-collections-on-cloudfunctions), just needed to specify:

```
const chatId = context.params.chatId;
const usersId = context.params.usersId;
```

Thanks @Frank van Puffelen!